# How to get the default system icon for a drive, a device or a file

Tags: delphi, winapi, icons

I am creating a remote file manager. The server side application gets the list of drivers, directories and files in the computer, saves it as stream and send it to me in the current computer where I am. Everything works fine.

In the current computer, first I use the "OnCreate" event to fill a TListImage with shell icons (from the same current computer) and link it with the ListView where the file list will be showed. So, once received the list, I use this funcion below to show the generic file icon in the ListView:

```
function GetGenericFileIconIndex(Filename: string): Integer;
var
  FInfo: TSHFileInfo;
begin
  Result := -1;
  if (SHGetFileInfo(PChar(Filename), FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, FInfo, SizeOf(FInfo),
    SHGFI_SYSICONINDEX or SHGFI_USEFILEATTRIBUTES) <> 0) then
    Result := FInfo.iIcon;
end;

for I := 0 to Pred(List.Count) do
begin
  Item := ListView.Items.Add;
  Item.ImageIndex := GetGenericFileIconIndex(List[I]);
  Item.Caption := List[I];
end;
```

With file name/extension I can get the correct shell icon, even in a different computer. But I also need to show the correct drive type icon. For example, on remote computer "D:\" is a local fixed drive, but on current computer "D:\" is a CD/DVD drive, so I cannot use the drive letter to get this icon. I need a way to get a "generic" drive type icon index from remote computer (fixed drive) and send it to the current computer.

For example, my goal is to obtain a *default icon* for a local hard dive, a *default icon* for a remote disk, a CD/DVD device and so on...

Sorry about mistakes, english is not my native language. I did my best to try to explain.

Maybe what I need is impossible, just let me know please...

Thanks!

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean by generic. Nor do I understand the point about using the information on a different computer.

Comment: Have you tried drive root ?

Comment: The (system icon) index you get is an index into a dynamically built structure (the system image list) for all shell icons, which is probably different on each computer. So what you want is probably impossible.

Comment: FWIW, what would a generic drive type icon be? On my computer, the icon for the boot drive (C:) is different than that for the second partition (D:) and both are different from the icons for the BD-ROM. What are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, english is not my native language, sorry. I edited the question for better explaining.

Comment: @TLama, I didn't. What you mean with "drive root"? Can you give me some example?

Comment: @RudyVelthuis, I am creating a list of drives in the remote computer and sending to the current computer. On remote computer, "D:\" is a local fixed drive. But on current computer "D:\" is a CD/DVD drive. I need a way to get the generic drive type icon index from remote computer and send it to the current computer.

Comment: @Paruba my advice is to complete your question with this *generic icon* image because I think that nobody has really understood what it actually is

Comment: @fantaghirocco, I edited the question again. Thanks!

Comment: Since the drive icons may be at different indices on different computers, you will have to stream the entire icon data too (obtainable with the same function, just different flags). Then you can build a simple image list and use your own indices for those drives. There will probably be no more than 26.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis, the entire shell icon list from my Windows 7 is about 1 MB size (1000 icons) :( ... But I made some new tests and realized that main drive icons have the same index in different computers and Windows versions. For example, DRIVE_REMOVABLE = 7, DRIVE_FIXED = 8, DRIVE_CDROM = 11... I did tests on Windows XP, 7, 8 and 10...

Comment: You said you could reconstruct normal file icons from the extension, even on the other computer. So you only need to stream the drive icons. If this is not the case, you'll have to stream all icons you might find and build your own dictionary. That could be a little too much, although it is what I have done for a local display.  I would either use a few standard icons or none at all. Note that you only need to stream the icons that are visible at a certain time and which you don't have yet. And that you can get more if more files become visible.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis, you are right, but the "fixed" indexes (7, 8, 11, ...), as I explained before, seems to work and solved my problem. Thank you!

Comment: Can you be sure that is the case for all computers on which this will be used? If so, then you found a solution. Otherwise, you did not.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You definitely have to use the [SHGetStockIconInfo function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762205(v=vs.85).aspx):

```
HRESULT SHGetStockIconInfo(
          SHSTOCKICONID   siid,
          UINT            uFlags,
  _Inout_ SHSTOCKICONINFO *psii
);
```

The `siid` parameter of type [SHSTOCKICONID](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762542(v=vs.85).aspx) is used to identify which *stock system icon* to retrieve.

```
function GetDefaultSystemIcon(ASiid: Integer): Integer;
var
  sInfo: TSHStockIconInfo;
begin
  sInfo.cbSize := SizeOf(TSHStockIconInfo);
  if S_OK = SHGetStockIconInfo(ASiid, SHGSI_SYSICONINDEX, sInfo) then
    Result := sInfo.iSysImageIndex
  else
    Result := -1;
end;
```

You may call the above like this `GetDefaultSystemIcon(SIID_DRIVECD)` to get the *default* CDROM drive icon index.

---

From the Microsoft documentation:

> Minimum supported client      *Windows Vista [desktop apps only]*
>   Minimum supported server    *Windows Server 2008 [desktop apps only]*

Older `ShellAPI` units may not have the `SHGetStockIconInfo` declaration: in this case the following `unit` must be added to the *Delphi* project.

Please **notice** that the use of the unit below is restricted to the availability of the `SHGetStockIconInfo` function in the *shell32.dll* system library - i.e. the library is required to export the function.

```pascal
unit MyShellAPI;

interface

uses
  Windows;

type
  SHSTOCKICONID = Integer;

  _SHSTOCKICONINFO = record
    cbSize: Cardinal;
    hIcon: HICON;
    iSysImageIndex,
    iIcon: Integer;
    szPath: packed array [0..MAX_PATH-1] of Char;
  end;
  SHStockIconInfo = _SHSTOCKICONINFO;
  TSHStockIconInfo = SHSTOCKICONINFO;
  PSHStockIconInfo = ^TSHStockIconInfo;

const
  //https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762179%28v=vs.85%29.aspx
  SHGFI_ADDOVERLAYS       = $000000020;
  SHGFI_ATTR_SPECIFIED    = $000020000;
  SHGFI_ATTRIBUTES        = $000000800;
  SHGFI_DISPLAYNAME       = $000000200;
  SHGFI_EXETYPE           = $000002000;
  SHGFI_ICON              = $000000100;
  SHGFI_ICONLOCATION      = $000001000;
  SHGFI_LARGEICON         = $000000000;
  SHGFI_LINKOVERLAY       = $000008000;
  SHGFI_OPENICON          = $000000002;
  SHGFI_OVERLAYINDEX      = $000000040;
  SHGFI_PIDL              = $000000008;
  SHGFI_SELECTED          = $000010000;
  SHGFI_SHELLICONSIZE     = $000000004;
  SHGFI_SMALLICON         = $000000001;
  SHGFI_SYSICONINDEX      = $000004000;
  SHGFI_TYPENAME          = $000000400;
  SHGFI_USEFILEATTRIBUTES = $000000010;

  //https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762205(v=vs.85).aspx
  SHGSI_ICONLOCATION = 0;
  SHGSI_ICON = SHGFI_ICON;
  SHGSI_SYSICONINDEX = SHGFI_SYSICONINDEX;
  SHGSI_LINKOVERLAY = SHGFI_LINKOVERLAY;
  SHGSI_SELECTED = SHGFI_SELECTED;
  SHGSI_LARGEICON = SHGFI_LARGEICON;
  SHGSI_SMALLICON = SHGFI_SMALLICON;
  SHGSI_SHELLICONSIZE = SHGFI_SHELLICONSIZE;

  //https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762542%28v=vs.85%29.aspx
  SIID_DOCNOASSOC         = 0;
  SIID_DOCASSOC           = 1;
  SIID_APPLICATION        = 2;
  SIID_FOLDER             = 3;
  SIID_FOLDEROPEN         = 4;
  SIID_DRIVE525           = 5;
  SIID_DRIVE35            = 6;
  SIID_DRIVEREMOVE        = 7;
  SIID_DRIVEFIXED         = 8;
  SIID_DRIVENET           = 9;
  SIID_DRIVENETDISABLED   = 10;
  SIID_DRIVECD            = 11;
  SIID_DRIVERAM           = 12;
  SIID_WORLD              = 13;
  SIID_SERVER             = 15;
  SIID_PRINTER            = 16;
  SIID_MYNETWORK          = 17;
  SIID_FIND               = 22;
  SIID_HELP               = 23;
  SIID_SHARE              = 28;
  SIID_LINK               = 29;
  SIID_SLOWFILE           = 30;
  SIID_RECYCLER           = 31;
  SIID_RECYCLERFULL       = 32;
  SIID_MEDIACDAUDIO       = 40;
  SIID_LOCK               = 47;
  SIID_AUTOLIST           = 49;
  SIID_PRINTERNET         = 50;
  SIID_SERVERSHARE        = 51;
  SIID_PRINTERFAX         = 52;
  SIID_PRINTERFAXNET      = 53;
  SIID_PRINTERFILE        = 54;
  SIID_STACK              = 55;
  SIID_MEDIASVCD          = 56;
  SIID_STUFFEDFOLDER      = 57;
  SIID_DRIVEUNKNOWN       = 58;
  SIID_DRIVEDVD           = 59;
  SIID_MEDIADVD           = 60;
  SIID_MEDIADVDRAM        = 61;
  SIID_MEDIADVDRW         = 62;
  SIID_MEDIADVDR          = 63;
  SIID_MEDIADVDROM        = 64;
  SIID_MEDIACDAUDIOPLUS   = 65;
  SIID_MEDIACDRW          = 66;
  SIID_MEDIACDR           = 67;
  SIID_MEDIACDBURN        = 68;
  SIID_MEDIABLANKCD       = 69;
  SIID_MEDIACDROM         = 70;
  SIID_AUDIOFILES         = 71;
  SIID_IMAGEFILES         = 72;
  SIID_VIDEOFILES         = 73;
  SIID_MIXEDFILES         = 74;
  SIID_FOLDERBACK         = 75;
  SIID_FOLDERFRONT        = 76;
  SIID_SHIELD             = 77;
  SIID_WARNING            = 78;
  SIID_INFO               = 79;
  SIID_ERROR              = 80;
  SIID_KEY                = 81;
  SIID_SOFTWARE           = 82;
  SIID_RENAME             = 83;
  SIID_DELETE             = 84;
  SIID_MEDIAAUDIODVD      = 85;
  SIID_MEDIAMOVIEDVD      = 86;
  SIID_MEDIAENHANCEDCD    = 87;
  SIID_MEDIAENHANCEDDVD   = 88;
  SIID_MEDIAHDDVD         = 89;
  SIID_MEDIABLURAY        = 90;
  SIID_MEDIAVCD           = 91;
  SIID_MEDIADVDPLUSR      = 92;
  SIID_MEDIADVDPLUSRW     = 93;
  SIID_DESKTOPPC          = 94;
  SIID_MOBILEPC           = 95;
  SIID_USERS              = 96;
  SIID_MEDIASMARTMEDIA    = 97;
  SIID_MEDIACOMPACTFLASH  = 98;
  SIID_DEVICECELLPHONE    = 99;
  SIID_DEVICECAMERA       = 100;
  SIID_DEVICEVIDEOCAMERA  = 101;
  SIID_DEVICEAUDIOPLAYER  = 102;
  SIID_NETWORKCONNECT     = 103;
  SIID_INTERNET           = 104;
  SIID_ZIPFILE            = 105;
  SIID_SETTINGS           = 106;
  SIID_DRIVEHDDVD         = 132;
  SIID_DRIVEBD            = 133;
  SIID_MEDIAHDDVDROM      = 134;
  SIID_MEDIAHDDVDR        = 135;
  SIID_MEDIAHDDVDRAM      = 136;
  SIID_MEDIABDROM         = 137;
  SIID_MEDIABDR           = 138;
  SIID_MEDIABDRE          = 139;
  SIID_CLUSTEREDDRIVE     = 140;
  SIID_MAX_ICONS          = 175;

function SHGetStockIconInfo(siid: SHSTOCKICONID; uFlags: UINT; var psii: TSHStockIconInfo): HRESULT; stdcall;

implementation

const
  SHELL32 = 'shell32.dll';

function SHGetStockIconInfo; external SHELL32 name 'SHGetStockIconInfo';

end.
```

Comment: Thank you fantaghirocco! I am researching about SHGetStockIconInfo for a while... Seems it cannot be used as simple as you show in your answer (please, correct if I am wrong). I am using Delphi 7. I found this link http://embarcadero.newsgroups.archived.at/public.delphi.language.delphi.win32/200902/0902022547.html and trying to synthesize the code in one simple function...

Comment: I edited the question with your sugestion. Please, could you try to help me again this last time? Thank you!

Comment: I reverted your edit. A new question is a new question. The AV is because you didn't call GetProcAddress to link to the function.

Comment: @Paruba while *Delphi 7* was released before *Windows Vista* you probably don't have `SHGetStockIconInfo` available in the `ShellAPI` unit. From the *MS* doc: *Minimum supported client
 Windows Vista [desktop apps only]*. I'll complete my answer with the the `unit` you have to add. The above works for me in *XE4*

Comment: @Paruba the solution in your link and my edit are basically the same. The main difference is the loading method of the *shell32.dll* which is *statically linked* in the case above. Ironically, the *dynamically linked* solution is itself "a link" :D

Comment: I would dynamically load the function b/c on XP your app would crash with the static link.

Comment: @kobik thanks I already noticed that. I'm googling to find the reason why to extend my answer

Comment: Note also, the newer ShellAPI unit declare this function as delay loaded. i.e. `function SHGetStockIconInfo; external shell32 name 'SHGetStockIconInfo' delayed;`

Comment: @kobik the *shell32.dll* in my WinXP installation does not exports the `SHGetStockIconInfo`: the app crashing is the expected behaviour for a statically linked library

Comment: @kobik the `delayed` keyword was added in *Delphi2010*, the OP refers to *D7* so I preferred to omit that feature. Also the OP reports a [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31805944/how-to-get-the-default-system-icon-for-a-drive-a-device-or-a-file/31812085?noredirect=1#comment51555860_31812085) in his comment where the library is *dinamically loaded* so this page shows already both the solutions