# Alternatives to ShellAPI to get file list and icons

Tags: windows, delphi, winapi

I need to build a file/folder tree with associated file icons and special locations like network computers.

Currently I'm using Shell API to achieve it: SHGetFileInfo, IShellFolder.EnumObjects and other functions.

It works fine most of the time, but occasionally, on customer's machines it causes various errors like random access violations deep in system libraries. Analyzing bug reports, some of those seem to be a result of 3rd party shell extensions which are loaded to my app's address space when the Shell API is used.

I'm thinking to somehow avoid using Shell API and do the job another way. What are the other good approaches to build a folder tree?

Comment: have a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31805944/how-to-get-the-default-system-icon-for-a-drive-a-device-or-a-file. This uses `SHGetStockIconInfo` approach. Anyway... shellAPI

Comment: AFAIK all the Delphi functions used to retrieve files and icons use the OS API internally (see `FindFirst`, `FindNext` for example). I think a different approach would be not feasible

Comment: To be more precise, I've just tested, and a call to SHGetFileInfo leads to 45 additional modules being loaded (it's on a clean dev machine, more of them on customer's). I'll check the SHGetStockIconInfo solution, thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Shell API is the way to do this

Comment: That's how it's done now, and what I want to avoid. As it turns out, calling SHGetStockIconInfo with the SHGSI_ICONLOCATION flag does not initiate module loading - a good start.

Comment: You won't be able to enumerate the shell name space

Comment: This is the wrong approach. *I have a problem with my application, and it can't be my fault, so let's avoid using the proper API and hack around it by trying to reinvent the wheel. Yeah, that's the ticket.* A better solution is to figure out what you're doing wrong. Windows Explorer uses the Shell API for everything, and since it clearly works with the same shell extensions loaded it can't be the API's fault. Fix your code.

Comment: I wish I could down vote condescending comments @KenWhite there's just no reason for this kind of attitude

Comment: @JohnEasley: Thanks for your feedback. Yes, you're right. The last three words of my previous comment should have been omitted.

Comment: @Ken the code is well tested and properly written, with all possible error checking and according to the docs. It works most of the time, but it fails under certain circumstances and randomly. Windows Explorer itself crashes too, by the way: when it encounters an unrecoverable error, it just restarts itself. I think everyone saw this happening. My app also restarts itself, but I'd like to move on and instead of restarting, reduce the crash probability.

Comment: The ShellAPI is the proper way to do what you're asking, and there isn't any alternative solution. If Explorer is crashing due to those extensions, the solution is to have your user uninstall those extensions. Trust me when I say that if Explorer is crashing too, no alternative solution (if it existed) would resolve the issue. Since you're enumerating the shell to retrieve network locations, you really don't have much choice. For folders and files, you could hack around using tons of code to try to do things, but *everything* on Windows ends up interacting with the shell at some point.

Comment: The question was created to explore possible alternatives. The solution I think of currently is to run shell functions in a separate app, use IPC and show the data in the main app. That helper app can crash all the way it wants :)

Comment: I agree with Ken White suggestion that your user should remove those Shell extensions that are causing the Windows Explorer to crash. You see Explorer crashing won't only lead to AV while you are attempting to get File list and icons. it would also cause AV while opening most of the common dialogs like OpenFile dialog. And it can also cause AV in some GUI related methods.

Comment: I personally remove any program that causes explorer to crash. Last time I did it was even thou I payed $30 for that program since the author of that program wasn't interested in fixing the issue. Also you and your customer must understand that explorer crashing might be result of some malicious software from trying to spread on that specific computer but is being stopped either by Anti Virus software or even more likely Windows DEP (Data Execution Prevention) which doesn't care which program does it kill. I have even seen DEP killing the hardware drivers because they were infected by a virus.

Comment: @KenWhite: Everything on Windows, that tries to mimic the shell, winds up interacting with the shell. Everything else on Windows doesn't. Your average `CreateWindowEx` call certainly won't be interacting with the shell. As for the *"if it works in Explorer, and not in your application, you're doing it wrong"* statement: If you knew the amount of compatibility shims implemented in Explorer, to deal with faulting shell extensions, you'd immediately revoke that assessment.

Comment: @IInspectable: The poster is trying to enumerate shell folders, which certainly *does* interact with the shell, no matter how you try and hack around it. I'm quite aware of the number of compatibility shims implemented as well, which was the reason that I said the best fix was to have the shell extension removed. Shell enumeration certainly does work in Explorer, and if it's working in Explorer on the system in question but not the poster's code, it's the poster's code that is at fault.

Comment: @KenWhite: How does that make your blunt statement, that "*everything* on Windows ends up interacting with the shell" right? It's blunt. And wrong. You appear to be aware of the fact, that Explorer works around bugs in shell extensions, yet continue to argue, that the poster's code is wrong. It may be perfectly fine, just not as resilient to bugs in 3rd party modules, as Explorer is. What strikes me as odd is, that you already identified those 3rd party modules as the culprits two comments up. You should certainly consider making up your mind.

Comment: @IInspectable: OK. Nitpick a comment in a discussion. It's not like I posted an **answer** or anything. You seem to want to start an argument here. Knock yourself out.

Comment: @IInspectable - I suppose you're right and Windows Explorer does have lots of fix-ups to deal with fauty extensions. For instance, I found by trial and error that sometimes EnumObjects function didn't work correctly when being called from multiple threads (it wasn't failing, but it returned incomplete set of objects). Same for SHGetFileInfo - calling this function has to be serialized as well. Not a word in the docs about it, though...

Comment: I don't believe that is true. EnumObjects does not need to be serialized.

Comment: @David, my tests showed that it does require. Two threads calling EnumObjects at the same time for the same path (it was cloned with ILClone) received an incomplete item list. May be the error was in somewhere else, but I decided to serialize EnumObjects as well. SHGetFileInfo needs to be serialized for sure anyway.

Comment: I think you have an error elsewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the problem really is due to faulty shell extensions then the only sensible approach, in my view, is to remove those shell extensions. Trying to work with the shell, but avoid using the shell API won't lead anywhere useful. In fact I think that the likely outcome is that your alternative code will be less functional. All for the sake of one user that won't fix their broken machine. That's a terrible trade off.

If explorer is also crashing then that is a clear indication that the problem is indeed due to shell extensions.

Having said all of that, you post makes me suspect that you have had bug reports from multiple clients. That makes your diagnosis much less plausible. The shell API is a complex beast and it is very plausible that your code is defective in some way. I suspect that you may be guilty of a case of *diagnosis by wishful thinking*. It's very easy, when facing a fault that is hard to reproduce and diagnose, to believe that your code is not to blame. If multiple clients are reporting problems then my bet is that the defect can be found in your code.

Comment: It's more like multiple bug reports from very few clients :) The reports indicate that it crashes even at simple calls, like getting the system image list handle. Reading the comments I suppose there's no alternative anyway, so I'll just re-check my code and that would be it.