# How to get the SHSTOCKICONID of a drive?

Tags: delphi, winapi, icons, delphi-10.3-rio

I have the same problem as [How to get the default system icon for a drive, a device or a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31805944/).

I want to display on MY system, a list of drives from ANOTHER system, but with the corresponding icons from that system. For this, I have to get the [`SHSTOCKICONID`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shellapi/ne-shellapi-shstockiconid) of a drive on the remote system, send it to my computer, and then get the icon index in my system image list based on that SIID.

The other question solves the last part of my problem, but I still have to find a way to get those SIID's of drives. Any ideas?

Comment: The SHSTOCKICONID is a fixed list for all Windows, so what's the first part of your question?

Comment: Giving a drive path " c:\ " , I want in return the `SHSTOCKICONID` of that drive.

Comment: There's no SHSTOCKICONID associated with anything. They are just a list of stock icons. You can determine the type of drive using other API (like GetDriveType https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-getdrivetypew) and choose what id to use, probably DRIVE_FIXED => SIID_DRIVEFIXED.

Comment: @SimonMourier, `GetDriveType` it gives me only a few drive types... but, anyway, it's better than nothing...

Comment: Seems your question doesn't match what you're looking for

Comment: Yes, it matches. I want to find the `SHSTOCKICONID` of a drive... Knowing the drive type returned by `GetDriveType` I can manualy map it to a `SHSTOCKICONID` for those few types...